# Issue with IPython/Jupyter on Spark (Unrecognized alias)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, ipython

I am working on setting up a set of VMs to experiment with Spark before I spend go out and spend money on building up a cluster with some hardware. Quick note: I am an academic with a background in applied machine learning and work quit a bit in data science. I use the tools for computing, rarely would I need to set them up.

I've created 3 VMs (1 master, 2 slaves) and installed Spark successfully. Everything appears to be working as it should. My problem lies in creating a Jupyter server that can be connected to from a browser not running on a machine on the cluster.

I've installed [Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook) successfully... and it runs. I've added a new IPython profile connecting to a [remote server](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html) with Spark.

### now the problem

The command

`$ ipython --profile=pyspark`
 
runs fine and it connects to the spark cluster. However,

`$ ipython notebook --profile=pyspark
[<stuff is here>] Unrecognized alias: "profile=pyspark", it will probably have no effect.`
 
defaults to the `default` profile not the `pyspark` profile.

My notebook config for `pyspark` has:

`c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8880
c.NotebookApp.server_extensions.append('ipyparallel.nbextension')
c.NotebookApp.password = u'some password is here'`

Comment: Could it be, that the following would work? `$ ipython --profile=pyspark notebook`? It might be that the problem was only with the order of the arguments.

Answer (score 12):

IPython has now moved to **[version 4.0](http://blog.jupyter.org/2015/08/12/first-release-of-jupyter/)**, which means that if you are using it, it will be reading its configuration from `~/.jupyter`, not `~/.ipython`. You have to create a new configuration file with

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

and then edit the resulting `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` file according to your needs.

More installation instructions [here](https://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html).

Comment: I've often wondered why they retained the ipython notebook command in splitting jupyter from ipython.  This is precisely why it gets really confusing. Thanks to you and kau zsh for pointing out the profile mismatch.  Its almost like they should use the ipython profile when using the ipython notebook command and the jupyter-notebook profile when using that command.

Answer (score 4):

Assume your configure file is ~/.ipython/profile_pyspark/ipython_notebook_config.py, you can still use this configure file by:

```
ipython notebook --config='~/.ipython/profile_pyspark/ipython_notebook_config.py'
```

or

```
jupyter-notebook --config='~/.ipython/profile_pyspark/ipython_notebook_config.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that pyspark is not on os sys path by default. After several failed attempt to add it manually to my config files/paths/etc, I came across [this GitHub](https://github.com/minrk/findspark) repository called findspark.

I cloned this repository using

```
git clone https://github.com/minrk/findspark.git
```

Then I ran `pip install findspark` from the findspark root.

Started a Jupyter notebook, created a new Python3 notebook and added

```
import findspark  
import os  
findspark.init()  
import pyspark  
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
```

Before `findspark.init()`, `import pyspark` came back with an error.

To test I just typed `sc` and got back:

```
pyspark.context.SparkContext at 0x4526d30
```

All working for me now.

Comment: Welcome to the site Anahita :)